# gazebo crashing

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I was trying to install nividia graphics and then Gazebo stopped loading.
I uninstalled it but still gazebo is crashing.

```
Msg Waiting for master
```

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error [RenderEngine.cc:638] Unable to create glx visual
Warning [RenderEngine.cc:90] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
[ INFO] [1354184856.288219264]: Laser plugin missing , defaults to 101
[ INFO] [1354184856.288542542]: INFO: gazebo_ros_laser plugin should set minimum intensity to 101.000000 due to cutoff in hokuyo filters.
Error [CameraSensor.cc:91] Unable to create CameraSensor. Rendering is disabled.
Error [CameraSensor.cc:91] Unable to create CameraSensor. Rendering is disabled.
[ WARN] [1354184856.431680299, 0.001000000]: Start robot with gravity turned off for all links.
[ WARN] [1354184856.431825603, 0.001000000]:   rostopic pub /mode std_msgs/String '{data: "nominal"}'
[ WARN] [1354184856.431906686, 0.001000000]: To re-engage.
[ INFO] [1354184856.498208440, 0.001000000]: starting gazebo_ros_controller_manager plugin in ns:
[ INFO] [1354184856.498356477, 0.001000000]: Callback thread id=0x7fe20801f030
[ INFO] [1354184856.505227749, 0.001000000]: gazebo controller manager plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [/robot_description] on the ROS param server.
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error [RenderEngine.cc:638] Unable to create glx visual
Warning [RenderEngine.cc:90] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
[ INFO] [1354184856.609494123, 0.001000000]: gazebo controller manager got urdf from param server, parsing it...
[ INFO] [1354184856.726055527, 0.001000000]: imu plugin missing , defaults to /default_imu
[INFO] [WallTime: 1354184857.048717] [0.322000] Loaded controllers: l_arm_elx_position_controller, r_arm_elx_position_controller, l_arm_ely_position_controller, r_arm_ely_position_controller, l_arm_mwx_position_controller, r_arm_mwx_position_controller, l_arm_shx_position_controller, r_arm_shx_position_controller, l_arm_usy_position_controller, r_arm_usy_position_controller, l_arm_uwy_position_controller, r_arm_uwy_position_controller, l_leg_kny_position_controller, r_leg_kny_position_controller, l_leg_lax_position_controller, r_leg_lax_position_controller, l_leg_lhy_position_controller, r_leg_lhy_position_controller, l_leg_mhx_position_controller, r_leg_mhx_position_controller, l_leg_uay_position_controller, r_leg_uay_position_controller, l_leg_uhz_position_controller, r_leg_uhz_position_controller, neck_ay_position_controller, back_lbz_position_controller, back_mby_position_controller, back_ubx_position_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1354184857.051747] [0.325000] Started controllers: l_arm_elx_position_controller, r_arm_elx_position_controller, l_arm_ely_position_controller, r_arm_ely_position_controller, l_arm_mwx_position_controller, r_arm_mwx_position_controller, l_arm_shx_position_controller, r_arm_shx_position_controller, l_arm_usy_position_controller, r_arm_usy_position_controller, l_arm_uwy_position_controller, r_arm_uwy_position_controller, l_leg_kny_position_controller, r_leg_kny_position_controller, l_leg_lax_position_controller, r_leg_lax_position_controller, l_leg_lhy_position_controller, r_leg_lhy_position_controller, l_leg_mhx_position_controller, r_leg_mhx_position_controller, l_leg_uay_position_controller, r_leg_uay_position_controller, l_leg_uhz_position_controller, r_leg_uhz_position_controller, neck_ay_position_controller, back_lbz_position_controller, back_mby_position_controller, back_ubx_position_controller
Warning [gazebo_main.cc:57] escalating to SIGKILL on server
[gazebo-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/nachum/.ros/log/637a9834-3a0f-11e2-a63b-24b6fd26a6b5/gazebo-2*.log

any ideas what should be done?

Thanks

Nachum

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49370/gazebo-crashing/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a problem with GLX (i.e. 3d acceleration) not being enabled on your computer and not really a problem that is Gazebo or ROS. You'll have to fix your X11 configuration. I suggest to re-enable the nvidia drivers and configure it correctly.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1